# How to change multiprocessing shared array size?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ctypes, python-multiprocessing

I want to create a shared array with a dynamic size. I want to assign an array with an unknown size to it in another process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array


def f(a):
    b=[3,5,7]
    #resize(a,len(b)) # How to resize "a" ???
    a[:]=b  # Only works when "a" is initialized with the same size like the "b"


arr = Array('d', 0) #Array with a size of 0

p = Process(target=f, args=(arr))
p.start()
p.join()

print arr[:]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of `mp.Arrays` can only be set once upon instantiation. You could use a [`mp.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) to create a [shared list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) however:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(mlist):
    b = [3, 5, 7]
    mlist[:]=b  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    mlist = manager.list()
    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=[mlist])
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(mlist[:])
```

yields

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

---

Note also `args=(arr)` results in

```
TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

because `args` expects a *sequence* of arguments to be passed to it. `(args)`
evaluates to `arr`. To pass `arr` to `f` you would need `args=[arr]` or
`args=(arr,)` (a tuple containing 1 element).

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem even more elegant!