# multiprocessing shared memory array not changing size within child process

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So this is kind of complicated, please bear with me. I am subclassing multiprocessing's Process class like so:

```
import dill
import multiprocessing as mp

class MyProcess(mp.Process):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = mp.Queue()
        self.array = mp.Array('i', [0,0,0]) # starts off with a size of 3 items

    def run(self):
        """retrieve serialized functions from the queue and call them"""
        while True:
            f = dill.loads(self.q.get())
            f(self.array) # pass the array as the first argument

    def my_method(self):
        """change the size of the array and make the values all equal 1"""

        # increment the size of the array by 1
        self.array = mp.Array('i', [0,0,0,0])
        
        # print here to show the size of the array before the function call
        print(len(self.array[:]))

        # define a nested function here to serialize and put in the queue
        def f(array):

            # print the size of the array here during the function call
            print(len(array[:]))

            # modify the array contents
            with array.get_lock():
                array[:] = [1,1,1,1]

        # serialize the function and put it in the queue
        self.q.put(dill.dumps(f))
```

The child process is retrieving serialized functions from a queue and calling them as the come in. These functions populate a shared array object that is subject to a change in size. When I instantiate the subclass and call the "my_method" method, I expect the size of the array to be increased to 4 prior to the function call; however, as you can see by the print statement this is not the case. The size of the array is still 3:

```
>>> p = MyProcess()
>>> p.start()
>>> p.my_method()
4
3
<traceback>
ValueError: Can only assign sequence of same size
```

Can someone explain why this happens?

EDIT: So I'm an idiot and this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330297/how-to-change-multiprocessing-shared-array-size). You can't change the size of a shared memory array after its been instantiated; however, you can use a list spawned with a multiprocess manager instance for storing dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change multiprocessing shared array size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330297/how-to-change-multiprocessing-shared-array-size)